# T-SQL check membership by AD Group guid

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, active-directory, row-level-security

I am looking at restricting access to a SQL Server database using row level security.

I know I can use `is_member(@groupname)` in order to determine if the currently logged in user is a member of the required group (or not).

But since that would break if someone where to rename the group I would like to use a more persistent identifier.

Is there a way to use something like the GUID of the group to determine membership?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SUSER_SID` function to retrieve a unique identifier (SID) for a Windows user or group. You can then use this SID to determine membership in row-level security (RLS) predicates.

You need to convert the binary SID to a hexadecimal string using sys.fn_varbintohexstr :

```sql
DECLARE @groupSID VARBINARY(85)
SET @groupSID = SUSER_SID('YourGroupName')
```

Then define your RLS predicate using the `sys.fn_replvarbinarymaxtohexsubstring` function to convert the SID to a hexadecimal string:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (
    ID INT,
    Column1 VARCHAR(50),
    Column2 INT
);

-- Enable RLS on the table
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD SECURITY POLICY YourRLSPolicy
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.YourRLSPredicate(ID) ON dbo.YourTable;
```

Try to ceate a function to define the RLS predicate and check membership based on the group SID:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourRLSPredicate (@ID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS RLSPredicateResult
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), SUSER_SID(),1) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @groupSID,1);
```

Comment: Thanks to your idea with the SID i found a Solution:
alter  function dbo.klientPredicate(@groupSID as VARBINARY(85))
returns table
with schemabinding
as
return select 1 as accessResult
where is_member(SUSER_SNAME(@groupSID))=1
go

create Security policy dbo.klientAccessPolicy 
 add filter predicate dbo.klientPredicate([SID]) on dbo.Stammdaten,
 add block predicate dbo.klientPredicate([SID]) on dbo.Stammdaten
go

Comment: However, i dont understand how the user SID could be equal to the group SID. At least thats how i understand your soulution

Comment: You don't need that function and you don't need to convert, you can just do `RETURN SELECT 1 AS RLSPredicateResult WHERE SUSER_SID() = 0x1234567890` directly

Comment: @Charlieface wouldn't that just check if the user sid and not any group membership?

Comment: @HenrikHalbritter True, that wasn't my point, more just about the unnecessary conversion. Note you are free to answer your own question below.